# Отправка пакетов на внешний IP адрес

Tags: c#, сетевое-программирование, wireshark

Отправляю собранный вручную пакет на адрес.

Для отправки какого-либо пакета на внешний IP нужен физический адрес получателя, который я не знаю как получить.

На ARP запросы сервер не отвечает, в отличие от компьютеров в локальных сетях.

PS Для отправки пакетов использую библиотеку SharpPcap.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, пакет нужно отправить в сторону шлюза по умолчанию, а дальше он сам разберётся

Comment: Разве для отправки на внешний ip недостаточно лишь знать external_IP+port?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko хорошо, но в пакете должен быть какой-то мак адрес, он там не забит нулями

Comment: А это точно c#? Может быть, вы перепутали с си?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko си шарп, для нет фреймворка есть библиотека SharpPcap, забыл её указать

Comment: @Адриян аа, тогда окей. А то искал именно `WinPcap` и натыкался только на си

Comment: 1) Читать про TCP/IP маршрутизацию. 2) Использовать TCP или UDP протокол, другие транспортные протоколы могут не пролезть через интернет. 3) Если вам нужно отправить пакет на шлюз, определите мак по его адресу и шлите, при чем шлюз должен понять пакет, ибо неведомо что он никуда дальше не отправит. 4) Мак удаленной машины вне локалки вам недоступен, и не должен быть доступен.